# Writing linear equation of Image in linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^3$ be the linear transformation defined by $T(x,y)=(y−x,−3x,−3y)$
>
> Write a linear equation defining the subspace $Im(T)$
>
> $\ldots =0$
>
> (Write your answer in the form $ax+by+cz$. For example $"2x+3y−4z"$)

So, I somehow learned how to find the image or kernels, but have no idea how to write a linear equation of it. Can someone help me with it? At least please give me an answer to this question I can figure out how to do it.

Comment: Please, use MathJax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\text{Im}(T)=\text{Span}\{T(1,0),T(0,1)\}=\text{Span}\{(-1,-3,0),(1,0,-3)\}.$$

Therefore, $$\text{Im}(T)=\{u(-1,-3,0)+v(1,0,-3)\mid u,v\in \mathbb R\}.$$

I let you find the cartesian equation.